# Adding new columns to a data.table by-reference within a function not always working

Tags: r, data.table

In writing a package which relies on `data.table`, I've discovered some odd behavior. I have a function which removes and reorders some column by-reference, and it works just fine, meaning the `data.table` I passed in was modified without assigning the function output. I have another function which adds *new* columns however, but those changes do not always persist in the `data.table` which was passed in.

Here's a small example:

```
library(data.table)  # I'm using 1.9.4
test <- data.table(id = letters[1:2], val=1:2)
foobar <- function(dt, col) {
    dt[, (col) := 1]
    invisible(dt)
}

test
#  id val
#1: a   1
#2: b   2
saveRDS(test, "test.rds")
test2 <- readRDS("test.rds")
all.equal(test, test2)
#[1] TRUE
foobar(test, "new")
test
#  id val new
#1: a   1   1
#2: b   2   1
foobar(test2, "new")
test2
#  id val
#1: a   1
#2: b   2
```

What happened? What's different about `test2`? I can modify existing columns in-place on either:

```
foobar(test, "val")
test
#  id val new
#1: a   1   1
#2: b   1   1
foobar(test2, "val")
test2
#  id val
#1: a   1
#2: b   1
```

But adding to `test2` still doesn't work:

```
foobar(test2, "someothercol")
.Last.value
#  id val someothercol
#1: a   1            1
#2: b   1            1
test2
#  id val
#1: a   1
#2: b   1
```

I can't pin down all the cases where I see this behavior, but saving to and reading from RDS is the first case I can reliably replicate. Writing to and reading from a CSV doesn't seem to have the same problem.

Is this a pointer issue ala [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480324/adding-a-large-number-of-columns-within-a-function-by-reference), like serializing a data.table destroys the over-allocated pointers? Is there a simple way to restore them? How could I check for them inside my function, so I could restore the pointers or error if the operation isn't going to work?

I know I can assign the function output as a workaround, but that's not very `data.table`-y. Wouldn't that also create a temporary copy in memory?

### Response to Arun's solution

Arun has instructed that it is indeed a pointer issue, which can be diagnosed with `truelength` and fixed with `setDT` or `alloc.col`. I ran into a problem encapsulating his solution in a function (continuing from above code):

```
func <- function(dt) {if (!truelength(dt)) setDT(dt)}
func2 <- function(dt) {if (!truelength(dt)) alloc.col(dt)}
test2 <- readRDS("test.rds")
truelength(test2)
#[1] 0
truelength(func(test2))
#[1] 100
truelength(test2)
#[1] 0
truelength(func2(test2))
#[1] 100
truelength(test2)
#[1] 0
```

So it looks like the local copy inside the function is being properly modified, but the reference version is not. Why not?

Comment: Fabulous question/explanations/reproducible example/motivation. Kudos. I can reproduce this even on the development version. Btw, you don't need the `invisible(dt)` part in your function IMO.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! I know I could have left it out, but for some reason I wanted to suppress printing. Thinking about it again, it may have been more clear to show the difference between function output and the original data.table. Oh well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this a pointer issue ala this issue, like serializing a data.table destroys the over-allocated pointers?

Yes loading from disk sets the external pointer to NULL. We will have to over-allocate again.

> Is there a simple way to restore them?

Yes. You can test for `truelength()` of the data.table, and if it's `0`, then use `setDT()` or `alloc.col()` on it.

```
truelength(test2) # [1] 0
if (!truelength(test2))
    setDT(test2)
truelength(test2) # [1] 100

foobar(test2, "new")
test2[]
#    id val new
# 1:  a   1   1
# 2:  b   2   1
```

<s>This should probably go in as a FAQ (can't remember seeing it there).</s>
Already in [FAQ](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html) in Warning Messages section.

Comment: Is there a reason to choose `setDT` over `alloc.col`?

Comment: No reason. I just chose `setDT()` because `alloc.col` doesn't return the result invisibly, so I'll have to wrap it with `invisible()`. `setDT()` seemed therefore shorter.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Since it'll be in a function, invisibility at this step doesn't matter, so I think `alloc.col` communicates intention better.
Thanks for the quick and accurate reply @Arun!

Comment: actually, this doesn't seem to work inside of a function, with either `setDT` or `alloc.col`. I can see the block trigger and bump up `truelength` using `browser`, but the table I pass in still isn't modified, and it's `truelength` is still 0 after the call, e.g. `func <- function(dt) {if (!truelength(dt)) setDT(dt)}`. Any ideas?

Comment: it does! It brings me to a conclusion I was hoping to avoid (gotta re-assign somewhere), but at least the copy is shallow.

Comment: Great. We'll try and see if this case can be improved. Could you file this as an issue please (not really an issue, but could be improved if possible)?