# data.table and R's ellipsis (i.e. '...'): pass by reference does not seem to work

Tags: r, data.table

Im trying to manipulate a large data table (~37 MB) but in a special way: for other (unrelated) reasons I have implemented a 'hook' like structure meaning that the overall process is like

1) load the data.table from disk

2) fire a certain hook

3) the hook structure looks for this name ans checks whether the user (=me :)) has bound a function to this hook and if so, it is called

4) the data is processed further

The functions look like this:

```
data = readRDS(pathToFile)
data = data.table(data)
fireHook("After_data_read", data, [some other parameters])
some_more_processing(data)
```

and the region around fireHook looks like

```
hooksRegistered = list(
  "After_data_read" = function(data, ...) { 
                        # do some stuff 
                      }


)

fireHook = function(hookName, ...) {
  for (hookNameRegistered in names(hooksRegistered)) {
    if (hookName == hookNameRegistered) {
      func = .global.hooksRegistered[[hookName]]
      func(hookName, ...)
    }
  }
}
```

Observe that one needs to cast an object that already *is* a data.table into it again (otherwise the pass-by-reference does not work), see [Adding new columns to a data.table by-reference within a function not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078640/adding-new-columns-to-a-data-table-by-reference-within-a-function-not-always-wor) and [Pass by reference bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614386/pass-by-reference-bug)

---

Problem: this line: `func(hookName, ...)` takes like forever (> 5 minutes).

---

The debugger never really gets into the function (so its not the code in the function that takes a long time) and I've tested it with small data.tables and it worked. Also, I noted that the following seems to work:

```
fireHook = function(hookName, ...) {
  args = list(...)
  for (hookNameRegistered in names(.global.hooksRegistered)) {
    if (hookName == hookNameRegistered) {
      func = .global.hooksRegistered[[hookName]]
      func(hookName, args)
    }
  }
}
```

(notice that I substituted `...` by `list(...)`). To me, it seems as if R is trying to copy the whole table when using `...`. Is this right/desired? Or am I using it wrong?

regards,

FW

Comment: What version of R are you using.  I have a foggy recollection that this may have changed in more recent versions.

Comment: `version` gives me the version String `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)`... so its not the newest but also not too old I guess...