# make loaded data.table modifiable by a function

Tags: r, data.table

I am loading some data.tables and want to create some new columns in them.

There is a [closely related question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090267/), but it is predicated on manually entering the name of each data.table. Here's my example:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

perf_attr = data.table(
    ID          = 1:2, 
    perf_date   = as.IDate("2015-12-18") + 0:1, 
    metro_pop   = 1e4*(1:2)
)

##### this part causes trouble ######
save(perf_attr, file = "tmp.rdata")
rm(perf_attr)
load("tmp.rdata")

add_vars = function(DT = data.table(), vars = list()){
    if (length(vars)) DT[, names(vars) := lapply(vars, . %>% `[[`(2) %>% eval)][]
    DT
} 

vars = list(
    perf_attr = list(  
        const           =   ~1,
        lpop            =   ~log(metro_pop),
        dum_weekend     =   ~weekdays(perf_date) %in% c("Friday", "Saturday")
    )
)

for (DTnm in names(vars)) add_vars(get(DTnm), vars[[DTnm]])

##### new columns should appear here, but don't ######
perf_attr 
#    ID  perf_date metro_pop medinc
# 1:  1 2015-12-18     10000  30000
# 2:  2 2015-12-19     20000  40000
```

*Comments*

1. The `get` doesn't seem to be central to the problem, since `add_vars(perf_attr, vars$perf_attr)` also fails.
2. If you skip the save/load part, it seems to work fine, with `perf_attr` modified by reference). It also works if I don't use a function, like:

   ```
   perf_attr[, names(vars$perf_attr) := lapply(vars$perf_attr, . %>% `[[`(2) %>% eval)]
   ```
3. I'm used to having internal selfref pointers messed up for loaded data.tables, but am not sure how to repair them to make this work. I tried various `lapply(mget(tables()$NAME), f)` and `for (DTnm in tables()$NAME){stuff}` hacks after the `load` line, but to no good effect.

Comment: Just re-stumbled on the linked question and am rereading it; I might delete this question if I find an answer that way.

Comment: Okay, problem solved-ish. Not sure if I should delete, dupe close or just leave it be to be modified when https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1017 is fixed up.

Answer (score 3):

Well, looking again at [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072152/), I came up with this loop to insert after `load`:

```
for (DTnm in tables()$NAME){
    assign(DTnm, alloc.col(get(DTnm)))
}
```

Of course, this tweaks all data.tables in memory.