# R data.table update join by reference within function

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update join two tables within a function. Here is an example without using a function:

```
library(data.table)
Xtest <- data.table(a = rnorm(20), b = rnorm(20), c = 1:20)
Ytest <- data.table(c = 1:10, d = rnorm(10))

Xtest[Ytest, on = .(c), newcol := i.d]

# > Xtest[Ytest, on = .(c), newcol := i.d]
# > Xtest
# a           b  c      newcol
# 1: -1.68473343 -0.74498296  1  0.35096663
# 2: -0.98461614  2.15317525  2 -1.33890396
# 3: -1.65427602  1.21183896  3  1.49641480
# 4: -0.65045253 -0.74609860  4 -0.03227097
# 5:  1.49058508  1.20315276  5  1.41580186
# 6: -0.31631871  0.68716871  6 -0.03671959
# 7:  1.35923085 -0.20082238  7 -2.27959124
# 8: -0.75649545  0.24058212  8  0.93770862
# 9:  0.22452260 -0.28212892  9 -0.02500419
# 10:  0.30209786  1.33697797 10  0.67729741
# 11:  0.88748221 -0.54421418 11          NA
# 12:  0.47207422 -0.28159382 12          NA
# 13: -1.17270475  0.83940750 13          NA
# 14: -2.02787820 -0.03672582 14          NA
# 15: -0.22187761  0.59137210 15          NA
# 16:  0.97750330 -0.27030756 16          NA
# 17:  0.22725940  0.54617488 17          NA
# 18:  0.94065525 -0.23482152 18          NA
# 19:  2.12049977  0.69920776 19          NA
# 20:  0.06192823  0.12262739 20          NA


# Xtest[, newcol := NULL]
```

I tried to recast the above code into a function, but the Ycol argument seems to be hidden:

```
myjoinfunction <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) {
  eval(substitute(X[Y, on = joinlist, newcol:=i.Ycol])) 
}

# > myjoinfunction <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) {
#   +   eval(substitute(X[Y, on = joinlist, newcol:=i.Ycol])) 
#   + }
# > myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, list(c), D, d)
# Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'i.Ycol' not found
# 8.
# eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame())
# 7.
# eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame())
# 6.
# `[.data.table`(Xtest, Ytest, on = list(c), `:=`(D, i.Ycol))
# 5.
# Xtest[Ytest, on = list(c), `:=`(D, i.Ycol)]
# 4.
# eval(substitute(X[Y, on = joinlist, `:=`(newcol, i.Ycol)]))
# 3.
# eval(substitute(X[Y, on = joinlist, `:=`(newcol, i.Ycol)]))
# 2.
# eval(substitute(X[Y, on = joinlist, `:=`(newcol, i.Ycol)]))
# 1.
# myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, list(c), D, d)
```

How can I make the Ycol argument visible within the function?

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

To be more general, here is a new example of an update join I would like to write a function for:

```
Xtest <- data.table(
a = rnorm(20), 
b = rnorm(20), 
c = rep(letters[1:4], rep(5, 4)), 
d = rep(1:5, 4)
)
Ytest <- data.table(
c = rep(letters[1:2], rep(5, 2)), 
d = rep(1:5, 2), 
e = rnorm(10), 
f = rnorm(10)
)

# > Xtest[Ytest, on = .(c, d), `:=`(newcol1 = i.e, newcol2 = i.f) ]
# > Xtest
# a            b c d    newcol1    newcol2
# 1: -2.4939743 -0.200370619 a 1 -1.4934893 -1.0288955
# 2:  1.0188321 -1.182286508 a 2  1.3811712  0.9747131
# 3:  0.5217161 -0.152117649 a 3 -0.4168069  0.1218213
# 4: -0.1584167  0.583640353 a 4  0.4644738  1.7888567
# 5: -0.4271398  0.020067301 a 5  2.5279998  2.0919953
# 6: -1.7692909  0.250129040 b 1 -1.5964246 -1.0884861
# 7: -0.8899915  0.971742055 b 2  0.3011304  1.2629524
# 8: -0.4490363 -1.540005621 b 3 -0.7992208 -0.5155775
# 9: -0.5706488 -1.037077614 b 4  1.0058213  1.9787692
# 10: -0.0922679  1.444487848 b 5 -0.2893311 -0.6095043
# 11:  0.9924810 -1.144513228 c 1         NA         NA
# 12:  1.2232591  1.503649791 c 2         NA         NA
# 13:  0.8751961  0.892765910 c 3         NA         NA
# 14:  0.9960554  0.499310073 c 4         NA         NA
# 15: -0.6184695  1.867985589 c 5         NA         NA
# 16:  0.6503936  0.422683211 d 1         NA         NA
# 17: -0.6160834 -1.585713893 d 2         NA         NA
# 18:  1.5949931 -0.544704857 d 3         NA         NA
# 19:  0.7232079 -0.006460518 d 4         NA         NA
# 20: -0.2824961  0.119585859 d 5         NA         NA
```

Using a suggestion from David Arenburg in the comments trips up when joinlist is a list of strings

```
myjoinfunction1 <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) X[Y, on = joinlist, newcol:= get(paste0("i.", Ycol))]

# > myjoinfunction1(Xtest, Ytest, list("c", "d"), "newcol", "e")
# Error in .parse_on(substitute(on), isnull_inames) : 
#   'on' argument should be a named atomic vector of column names indicating which columns in 'i' should be joined with which columns in 'x'.
# 5.
# stop("'on' argument should be a named atomic vector of column names indicating which columns in 'i' should be joined with which columns in 'x'.")
# 4.
# .parse_on(substitute(on), isnull_inames)
# 3.
# `[.data.table`(X, Y, on = joinlist, `:=`(newcol, get(paste0("i.", 
#                                                             Ycol))))
# 2.
# X[Y, on = joinlist, `:=`(newcol, get(paste0("i.", Ycol)))]
# 1.
# myjoinfunction1(Xtest, Ytest, list("c", "d"), "newcol", "e")
```

Comment: Try `myjoinfunction <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) X[Y, on = joinlist, newcol:= get(paste0("i.", Ycol))]`, then `myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, "c", "newcol", "d") ; Xtest`

Comment: That does arrive at the desired output, however, is there any way to make the Ycol argument visible within  `eval(substitute(xxx))` ? By using `eval` and `substitute`, I don't need the other arguments as strings but they can be typed directly. It might not matter in the end but I'm just curious if it can be done.

Comment: Try `myjoinfunction <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) {Ycol <- paste0("i.", as.character(substitute(Ycol)));X[Y, on = eval(substitute(joinlist)), as.character(substitute(newcol)) := get(Ycol)] };myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, list(c, d), newcol, e);Xtest`

Comment: `joinlist` should be a vector of strings like `c(...)` rather than a list.

Comment: @Frank Why? It can be a list too. You can parse it using `eval(substitute(joinlist))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm responding to the error at the end of the OP where you can see they called the function with `list("c", "d")` which is not supported. `on=` is flexible but that pattern doesn't work (or used to not work?), which I guess is where the error comes from. I suggested strings instead of `list(c, d)` since I'm guessing the OP wants to pass the colnames programmatically. `eval(substitute(list("c", "d")))` is just the same list again, so I guess that's not a workaround

Comment: In fact, in this case, I'm intending the function for interactive use (which I didn't mention in the original question), so it's more convenient not to have strings. However, it's also correct that this is not useful in a programmatic environment.

Answer (score 2):

For the more general second example:

```
f <- function(X, Y, joinlist, cols) {
    X[Y, on = joinlist, names(cols) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", cols))]
}
```

Usage:

```
set.seed(1)
Xtest2 <- data.table(
a = rnorm(20), 
b = rnorm(20), 
c = rep(letters[1:4], rep(5, 4)), 
d = rep(1:5, 4)
)
Ytest2 <- data.table(
c = rep(letters[1:2], rep(5, 2)), 
d = rep(1:5, 2), 
e = rnorm(10), 
f = rnorm(10)
)

f(Xtest2, Ytest2, c("c", "d"), c(newcol1 = "e", newcol2 = "f"))
```

Side note: There are some edge cases to watch out for when adding columns in a data.table ([running out of "column slots"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480324/adding-a-large-number-of-columns-within-a-function-by-reference); [adding to a table loaded from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078640/adding-new-columns-to-a-data-table-by-reference-within-a-function-not-always-wor))

Comment: This is a potentially a nice solution for a programmatic environment, but it isn't exactly what I want right now, which unfortunately I didn't completely specify in my question (I am looking for something to be used interactively and it's slightly easier not to type strings). But I learnt something new in any case, nice to have options!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer based on the comments. The `eval` and `substitute` can be applied at different locations within the data.table, instead of wrapping the entire data.table in `eval(substitute(DT))`. Also, when using `substitute` with a string instead of an expression, `eval` is not needed.

```
myjoinfunction <- function(X, Y, joinlist, newcol, Ycol) {
  Ycol <- paste0("i.", as.character(substitute(Ycol))[-1])
  X[
     Y, 
     on = eval(substitute(joinlist)), 
     as.character(substitute(newcol))[-1] := mget(Ycol)
   d] 
  }
```

Usage:

```
set.seed(42)
Xtest <- data.table(
a = rnorm(20), 
b = rnorm(20), 
c = rep(letters[1:4], rep(5, 4)), 
d = rep(1:5, 4), 
id = 1:20
)
Ytest <- data.table(
c = rep(letters[1:2], rep(5, 2)), 
d = rep(1:5, 2), 
e = rnorm(10), 
f = rnorm(10), 
id = 1:10
)

# multiple columns supported both for joining and updating
myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, list(c, d), list(newcol1, newcol2), list(e, f));

# Single columns have to be expressed in a list
myjoinfunction(Xtest, Ytest, list(id), list(newcol1), list(e));
```

By not having the arguments as strings, this is better for interactive use than programmatic use.

Suggestions for refinements are welcome! Especially if there is a more elegant way to express single columns in the function arguments or handle lists within the function (I don't like having to use `[-1]` as a workaround within the function when handling lists, I think it will lead to errors eventually.)

Comment: Re lists vs singletons, you can wrap it in a helper function, `extract_symbols <- function(symbol_list){sub_list = substitute(symbol_list); syms = if (length(sub_list) == 1) sub_list else sub_list[-1]; as.character(syms)}` examples: `extract_symbols(list(c,d)); extract_symbols(c)`